# Calculate age based on three dates

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am trying to calculate the age of horses. All horses share the same birthday regardless of the date they were born - the 1st of August. For example, if a horse was born on 31st of July, it would still be classified as 1 yo despite only being one day old.

I have a dataframe with three columns: FoalDate (the day horse was born), MeetingDate (the day of race meeting), and Age. I am trying to calculate the horses age on a particular meeting date. In the example below, the horse would be a 2 yo because the 1st of August has only passed twice since its foal date.

Example:

```
Foal Date     MeetingDate   Age
20/11/2014    30/04/2017    2
```

I am trying to write code that would replace the 'Age' column (which is currently filled with 0s) with the correct answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'Foal Date': {0: '20/11/2014', 1: '31/07/2015', 2: '31/07/2015', 3: '31/08/2015'},
        'MeetingDate': {0: '30/04/2017', 1: '30/04/2017', 2: '01/08/2017', 3: '01/11/2015'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    Foal Date   MeetingDate
0   20/11/2014  30/04/2017
1   31/07/2015  30/04/2017
2   31/07/2015  01/08/2017
3   31/08/2015  01/11/2015
```

---

**Code**

```
# make dtype to datetime
df1 = df.apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%Y')

s1 = df1['Foal Date'].dt.month < 8
s2 = df1['MeetingDate'].dt.month >= 8
s_age = df1['MeetingDate'].dt.year.sub(df1['Foal Date'].dt.year).sub(1).add(s1).add(s2)
```

`s_age`

```
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    0
dtype: int64
```

make s_age to age column

```
df.assign(Age=s_age)
```

result:

```
    Foal Date   MeetingDate Age
0   2014-11-20  2017-04-30  2
1   2015-07-31  2017-04-30  2
2   2015-07-31  2017-08-01  3
3   2015-08-31  2015-11-01  0
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the `datetime` library when using `python`.

Initially get the year from the **Foal Date** and then create a another datetime object for the **Birth Date** using that particular year. To make it more efficient we can consider an `if else` statement to check if the month >= august in order to decide on whether to consider that year or the previous year.

Then by finding the difference between the **Birth Date** and **Meet Date** the age can be found in days.

```
import datetime;

foalDate = datetime.datetime(2014,3,20)
foalMonth = foalDate.month
if foalMonth >= 8:
    foalYear = foalDate.year 
else:
    foalYear = foalDate.year - 1

birthDate = datetime.datetime(foalYear,8,1)
print(f'birthDate : {birthDate}')
meetDate = datetime.datetime(2017,4,30)
print(f'meetDate : {meetDate}')
age = meetDate - birthDate

print(f'Age is {(age.days)//365}')
```

You can run and check the code: https://www.online-python.com/GfIezdmbNr

Hope I answered your question.